# Deviation with virtual keyword

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have below structure defied as

```
struct A{
    string s;
    A() {
        cout<<"in a default\n";
    }
    A(string t): s(t) {
        cout<<"in a param \n";
    }
};

struct B: virtual public A{
    B(): A("B"){

        cout<<"in b\n";
    }
};

struct C: virtual public A {};
struct D: public B, public C {};
int main()
{
D d;
}
```

with A as virtual base class in both C and B,output is as follows

```
in a default
in b
```

With A as virtual base class for only B ,output is as follows

```
in a default
in b
in a default
```

with A as virtual base class for only C ,output is as follows

```
in a default
in a param 
in b
```

and with no virtual base class ,output is as follows

```
in a param 
in b
in a default
```

can any one explain me the deviation?

Comment: Because that's what virtual base classes mean. They only occur once in the chain of superclasses.

Comment: Why in first case it was in a default and not in a param?

Comment: Virtual class is a special case of multipath inheritance, which is avoid the duplicate data from the same base class.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual inheritance is there to resolve what's known as the "Diamond of death"

In summary, the issue is that if you called D::[some function in A], which A would it pick - the one from B, or the one from C, or that makes no sense that the separation exists?

You can read more about the issue here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem